# log4net style interface in F# -- static method returns instance of object

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'm trying to build a log4net style interface in an F# assembly. The key attribute is exposing a static method that returns an instance of an object. log4net makes use of C# delegates to accomplish the task, e.g. with `LogManager.GetLogger("log123")`. Delegates, from my understanding, are less favored than functions-as-first-class for inward-facing F# libraries.

The simplified code below accomplishes the objective, but I am uncomfortable with the use of an F# reference cell to hold a map of instantiated objects. I am interested in feedback on whether my discomfort is warranted.

```
namespace Test
[<Interface>]
type IMyIface =
    abstract member Addi : int -> int
[<Sealed>]
type TheMainObject internal (x:int) = 
    let mutable sum = x
    interface IMyIface with
        member this.Addi(y:int) = sum <- sum + y; sum 
module internal Wrapr = 
    let mymap = ref Map.empty
    let mgr s = 
        let m = !mymap
        if Map.containsKey s m then m.[s] 
        else 
            let x = new TheMainObject(0)
            mymap := m.Add(s, x)
            x 
[<Sealed>]
type Mgr() = 
    static member Get(n:string) = 
        Wrapr.mgr n :> IMyIface
```

Program.fs calls the library above as follows:

```
open Test
let a = Mgr.Get("hello")
printfn "%d" (a.Addi(1)) 
let c = Mgr.Get("hello")
printfn "%d, %A" (c.Addi(3)) (a = c) //prints 4, true
```

Thanks in advance for comments.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to use a [reference cell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx) internally to hold a mutable value. You could also use a .Net [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of a map. This is the approach I took while building a [Mini IoC Container](http://fssnip.net/9g). If you expect the function accessing the reference cell to be called from multiple threads then you should probably use a [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370413.aspx) or other [thread synchronization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29#Thread_or_process_synchronization).

There are a number of ways of exposing the Get method. The static member approach you have taken is useful if you expect to overload the method. In which case you may consider using [static let](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483470.aspx) for static locals over a separate module:

```
type [<Sealed>] Mgr() =     
    static let sync = obj()
    static let lookup = Dictionary()
    static let obtain name =
        match lookup.TryGetValue(name) with
        | true, x -> x
        | false,_ ->        
            let x = TheMainObject(0)
            lookup.Add(name,x)
            x
    static member Get(name:string) = 
        lock sync (fun () -> obtain name :> IMyIface)
```

If you do not expect to overload the Get function then you could just use a module:

```
module Mgr =
    let private lookup = ref Map.empty
    let private obtain name =
        match (!lookup).TryFind name with
        | Some(x) -> x
        | None ->        
            let x = TheMainObject(0)
            lookup := (!lookup).Add(name,x)
            x
    let Get name = obtain name :> IMyIface
```